# How to draw table diagrams.

Tags: diagrams

How can I create diagrams like below, with tables and arrows.

[image]

I am looking for boilerplate code on which I can build on further. 
Secondly, is there any other tool which can make drawing such images fast.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this; your questions is pretty broad.  Are you looking for something embedded in TeX code?  Something that you precompile and use in many different documents?  Does it need to be in a format that you can directly use in non-TeX documents?  Have you experimented with any solutions, and if so, with what result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a starter to give you some idea of what you can do.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%% I define a "style" for the "cells"
\tikzset{
  my cell/.style={
    draw,
    minimum size=5ex,
    node distance=0pt,
  }}
%% to make changing appearances for various aspects of         
%% the diagram easier, I define several macros which need      
%% only be changed here.  Even though two of these macros      
%% have the same definition, I use two to allow the possibility
%% that these styles could be diffferent.                      
\newcommand\mynodestyle{\sffamily}
\newcommand\myrelocatestyle{\sffamily\bfseries}
\newcommand\mynumberstyle{\sffamily}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
  %--- BEFORE ---%
  \node[my cell] (before/0) {};
  \node[anchor=east] at (before/0.west) {0};
  %% \myn=node name    
  %% \myc=node content 
  %% \myp=previous node
  \foreach \myn/\myc [remember=\myn as \myp (initially 0)] in {1/,2/b,3/,4/c,5/,6/a,7/}
  {
    \node[my cell,below=of before/\myp] (before/\myn) {\mynodestyle\myc};
    \node[anchor=east] (before/\myn/label) at (before/\myn.west) {\mynumberstyle\myn};
  }
  %% right hand anotations
  \draw[dashed,arrows=->] (before/6.east) 
                          to[out=30,in=-30,looseness=2] 
                          node[midway,right ] {\myrelocatestyle relocate}
                          (before/4.east);
  \draw[dashed,arrows=->] (before/4.east) 
                          to[out=30,in=-30,looseness=1.5] 
                          node[midway,right ] {\myrelocatestyle relocate}
                          (before/1.east);

  %% left hand anotations
  \path  (before/5) ++ (175:8em) node (item/x) {item $x$};
  \draw[arrows=->] (item/x) -- node[midway,left,yshift=2ex,xshift=1ex] {$h_1(x)$} (before/2/label);
  \draw[arrows=->] (item/x) -- node[midway,below,xshift=-1ex]          {$h_2(x)$} (before/6/label);

  \node[below=0.5cm of before/7] {(a) before inserting item $x$};

  %--- AFTER ---%
  %% Here's a slightly different approach to placing the contents of 
  %% each node.
  \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,7}
  {
    \def\myc{}
    \ifnum\myn=6\relax\def\myc{x}\fi
    \ifnum\myn=4\relax\def\myc{a}\fi
    \ifnum\myn=2\relax\def\myc{b}\fi
    \ifnum\myn=1\relax\def\myc{c}\fi
    \node[my cell,right=6cm of before/\myn] (after/\myn) {\mynodestyle\myc};
    \node[anchor=east] (after/\myn/label) at (after/\myn.west) {\mynumberstyle\myn};
  }

  \node[below=0.5cm of after/7] {(b) after item $x$ inserted};


%--- summary ---%
\foreach \myn in {0,1,...,7}
{
  \node[my cell,right=6cm of after/\myn] (summary/\myn/a) {};
  \node[anchor=east] (summary/\myn/label) at (summary/\myn/a.west) {\mynumberstyle\myn};
  \foreach \mycol [remember=\mycol as \mypcol (initially a)] in {b,c,d}
  {
    \node[my cell,right=of summary/\myn/\mypcol] (summary/\myn/\mycol) {};
  }
}

\foreach \mycol in {a,b,c}
{
  \draw[white,dashed,line width=0.9pt] ($(summary/0/\mycol.north east)+(0,-2pt)$) -- ($(summary/7/\mycol.south east)+(0,2pt)$);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not exactly boiler plate, but should be enough to get you started and finished.

Comment: I was just wondering whether you could post the compiled figure? That makes it easier for other people to understand what is going on in your code. Thanks.

Comment: @phx Whoa dude.  You're quick on the draw.  I'm still adding details.  LOL.  :-)